# How to learn about KVC with swift 4.2

Tags: swift, kvc

I'm using Xcode 10.0 with swift 4.2 to learn about Key Value Coding from "Cocoa programming for OSX"

I'm asked to create a simple class, which is a subclass of NSObject. The codes below:

```
import Cocoa

class Student: NSObject {
    var name: String = ""
    var gradeLevel: Int = 0
}

let student1 = Student()


student1.setValue("Benny", forKeyPath: "name")
```

**student1.setValue("Benny", forKeyPath: "name")**

Generates the following error message:

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

I've looked online and seem some issues regarding KVC such as :
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5139

What am I doing wrong? The book was published in 2015.

Comment: Did you read the full bug report? *"Swift 4 no longer exposes properties to Objective-C by default unless they're overriding something or satisfying a protocol requirement. **Use the objc attribute** to expose them explicitly.
You can read more about this in the Xcode 9 release notes."*

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Yes I did read the full report, and thought of reading the Xcode 9 release notes. The report was from 2017. I just didn't want to go down the wrong rabbit hole chasing things and though it best to ask.

Comment: See [Key-path Expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID563) in the Swift book.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Swift 4 exposing code to the Objective-C runtime is no longer inferred for performance reasons.
To avoid the crash you have to add the `@objc` attribute explicitly.

```
@objc var name: String = ""
```

---

But from the strong type perspective of Swift there are two better ways to get values with KVC:

1. The `#keyPath` directive which uses the ObjC runtime, too, but checks the key path at compile time

   ```
   let keyPath = #keyPath(Student.name)
   student1.setValue("Benny", forKeyPath: keyPath)
   ```

   In this case you get a very descriptive compiler warning

   > Argument of '#keyPath' refers to property 'name' in 'Student' that depends on '@objc' inference deprecated in Swift 4
2. The (recommended) native way: Swift 4+ provides its own KVC pattern where subclassing `NSObject` is not required.
   Key paths are indicated by a leading backslash followed by the type and the property (or properties):

   ```
   class Student {
       var name: String = ""
       var gradeLevel: Int = 0
   }

   let student1 = Student()
   student1[keyPath: \Student.name] = "Benny"
   ```

Comment: This is really interesting and a perfect answer.... i will take @Martin_R suggestion to and read XC9 release notes... soon ! thanks

Comment: There must be another way to do this that falls in with swift. The syntax doesn't look right the back slash is out of place and uneeded

Comment: Please watch [WWDC 2017 : What's new in Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/) from 4:30

Comment: OK here is 57 minutes of my life ;)

Comment: There are worse ways to waste life time  Watch the video and you will understand the syntax

Comment: 21 minutes in and the I'm listening about KVO which I really wanted to ask but thought I'd get the "Off topic" beat down. Thanks man :) really good video. I wish I got 30% of what they are talking about but will watch again in 1 month. Do you have a link to more ?

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Example of KVC**

Here we access the name property of SimpleClass directly through the instance.

```
class SimpleClass {
var name: String
init(name: String) {
    self.name = name

   }
 }

let instance = SimpleClass(name: "Mike")
let name = instance.name
print("name: \(name)")
```

But in KVC Here we access the name property of the class through forKey.

```
class KVCClass: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let instance = KVCClass(name: "Mike")
if let name = instance.value(forKey: "name") as? String {
    print("name: \(name)")
}
```